# Shell script for logrotating

Tags: shell, shell-script, scripting

I want to create a **shell script** for **logrotating**. following are my requirement.

1. want to archive the log files to a particular directory lets(/usr/local/jboss-5.10..GA/server/archive/log) older than **2** months .
2. want to delete logs older than 2 months from archive directory. the format of log is server.log.2015-08-11

   ```
   server.log.2015-02-06
   server.log.2015-02-07
   server.log.2015-02-08
   server.log.2015-02-09
   server.log.2015-02-10
   server.log.2015-02-11
   server.log.2015-02-12
   server.log.2015-02-13
   server.log.2015-02-14
   server.log.2015-02-15
   ```

the log files are present on below path

```
cd /usr/local/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/pymidol/log/
```

Comment: Is using `logrotate` an option? `man logrotate` for details

Comment: Sir , i have checked it but not able to make a script .if u can show me the format according to my need then it will be very helpul to me ..

Comment: Does `jboss` create the dated log files? If so, you don't need logrotation as `jboss` already does that; you simply need archiving. Please clarify in your Question.

Comment: yes sir but for space management we have to delete logs manually ..so i was seacrhing for a script which can do all my requirement accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first create some space by removing files

for your (2) question for removing the files from arhive directory

```
find /usr/local/jboss-5.10..GA/server/archive/log -type f  -name server.log.* -mtime +60 -exec rm {} \;
```

for your (1) question

```
find /usr/local/jboss-5.10..GA/server/pymidol/log -type f  -name server.log.* -mtime +60 -exec mv {} /usr/local/jboss-5.10..GA/server/archive/log  \;
```

Comment: thanks sir for your answer but i want to zip the logs when they move to archive directory\

Comment: so instead of -exec mv ... use -exec gzip

Comment: sir if i use exec gzip and will they move to archive directory as u told to remove  -exec mv command

Comment: yes replace -exec mv with -exec gzip

Comment: Thanks sir , for your valuable time ... if i will have any query regarding it i will surely post it regarding this topic.